# Implementing a bare-bones COM object

Tags: c++, com

I need to implement a bare-bones COM object in straight C++ (no ATL) that is used by a legacy web application to check that my application exists.  The web application does something like this (JavaScript):

`var object = new ActiveXObject("My.Application");`

I want to ensure that the above succeeds but thats all I need to do - I do not need to implement any methods/properties on this object as they are never called.

Obviously I need to ensure that my object is registered by adding the necessary registry settings, etc.  My application is a DLL so I guess I also need to implement a handful of exported functions (DllRegisterServer, DllUnregisterServer, DllCanUnloadNow and, the one that has to so something, DllGetClassObject).

I'm pretty sure that simply returning S_OK from DllGetClassObject won't cut it.

How can I go about implementing a basic interface without using ATL?  I am using the MS compiler if that helps.

Comment: Why exactly don't you want ATL?

Comment: It's a dependency I've been told not to use.  Out of my hands I'm afraid.

Comment: That's reduculous. You can statically link to ATL so you don't need to carry the ATL.dll around - and noone will even see it **and** it will save you a ton of time and bugs. Your best best is to negotiate ATL usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not sufficient to build a bare-bones COM object. For starters, that would be so bare-bones that there's no name associated with it. You've already discovered that you need an object factory, too.

So, yes, implement `DllGetClassObject`. You'll have to check the input `rclsid` argument. This is an interface identifier. If you don't recognize it, return `CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE`. Apparently, because of hackerish approaches (like the unconditional S_OK you suggested) [Microsoft now passes at least one invalid class ID.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/11/71307.aspx). If you lie, and claim you can do it, Windows will not believe anyhting else you say.

So, what interfaces should you claim? Obviously `IUnknown` - it's the very root of the system. The most bare-bone COM object doesn't do anything else. You need more interfaces, though - the web app is asking for an *ActiveX* object. That requires more interfaces. Possibly the easiest approach would be to just see what Windows is asking for. I suspect you'll need at least IDispatch.

Next, you'll have to implement a few methods. "Wait", you may say, "they're not called". Well, `IDispatch` is a kind of meta-interface for scripting langauges. It's used to enumerate which methods are available. Hence, *your* `IDispatch` interface should support such enumeration as well, even though it would return zero scriptable methods.

There's a lot more detail, but this should already be sufficient to help convince you to use ATL and grab its ActiveX code. That's going to be far more complete than anything I can list here.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I implemented a simple object and factory and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There is *nothing* bare-bones about a COM server that supports late binding from Javascript running inside IE.  If you don't know how to implement DllGetClassObject() then you need all the help you can get.  You get a lot of help from ATL and the wizards built into Visual Studio.  The vast majority of the fugly plumbing code is auto-generated, including those 4 exports.  And IDispatch, the interface that the Javascript needs.

Start the project with the ATL + ATL Project template.  The defaults are good.  Right-click the project, Add, Class and select ATL + ATL Simple Object.  Switch to Class View, locate your interface type and right-click it to add methods and properties.